# An error occurred in the uploading images in wordpress version 3.8

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, content-management-system

here is my snapshot [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D31BT.png

i have spend several hours to resolve problem but fail to do that. though im new  in wordpress.

q:) when click on add Media button it provide option to upload image .when click on upload its shows an error  failed to upload images.
so where im wrong. i came to know good blog  url:http://classforbeginner.blogspot.in/2013/04/wordpress-image-upload-error.html..
i have tried all steps and tutorials of wordpress .

here is my php.ini file

short_open_tag = On  ,magic_quotes_gpc = Off ,magic_quotes_sybase = Off,magic_quotes_runtime = Off ,register_globals = Off ,upload_max_filesize = 20M ,post_max_size = 100M, session.auto_start = Off ,suhosin.session.encrypt = Off

i have troubleshoot
 by echo   phpinfo(); 
its will show gd library

3:) also test GD Libarary :

here is my code to test gdlib

if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) 
    echo "PHP GD library is installed on your web server";

else 
    echo "PHP GD library is NOT installed on your web server";

so where im wrong????

Comment: Plaese help me though im new bie in wordpress please tell where im  wrong

Comment: that is because might be you don't have PHP's GD extension activates

Comment: What does it say in your log file? That's where the real error will be displayed.

Comment: all possiblty has been tried but all in vain.. i  have googled and find there is problem in version 3.8 in image uploading.

Comment: its seems to work fine  in older version.

Comment: please give correct answer so that i can recitify this problem soon

Answer (score 0):

Debug with these points:

1. Check Files and folders permission of wp-uploads folder should be `655` or `777`
2. Check GD library is active or not
3. Check upload_max_filesize, post_max_size in your php.ini file

Comment: i have checked gd library installed

Comment: I wouldn't recommend 777, you're better off with 755 (you don't need to execute anything that has been upload from the WordPress backend). And especially don't give 'world' all rights on the files.

Answer (score 0):

Try turn off modul "imagemagick" in PHP settings